# Cannot set the correct path of image using jquery in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am setting the path of the image using jquery in the success part of ajax . My image folder tree is like

```
Project name
 |
 -application
 -system
 -user_guide
 -image
  |
  -img_412.png
```

i am setting the image path like this

```
success: function(data){

$('.img_container').attr("src",'image/img_412.png');

}
```

but the image is not shown and when i inspect element i find this url :

but on placing cursor on src i get the full path as following

```
http://localhost/MyProject/create_user/add_info/image/img_412.png
```

where create_user is the name of the controller and add_info is the method of the controller

I want to remove both from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
$('.img_container').attr("src",'<?php echo base_url("image/img_412.png"); ?>');
```

Ensure you load url helper in the controller or autoload that helper

Comment: Thanks Norlihazmey Ghazali it is working but i want to ask one thing more if i update this image i didn't get the updated image because the url is same how could i make this work.

Comment: welcome, cant reproduce the problem you encounter, can you elaborate more about this upcoming problem

Comment: I mean that i when i update that same image through ajax till i refresh my page i don't get the updated image. I think that's because the image url is same whats the solution.

Comment: oh i see. Do you ever try to update like this `$('.img_container').attr("src",'<?php echo base_url("' +  variable +'"); ?>');`, and variable hold the image path like `image/img_412.png`